# Loading files during run time

Tags: xna-4.0, loading, xna-content-pipeline, hot-reload

I made a content pipeline extension (using [this](http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/content-pipeline-extension-1) tutorial) in XNA 4.0 game.

I altered some aspects, so it serves my need better, but the basic idea still applies. Now I want to go a step further and enable my game to be changed during run time. The file I am loading trough my content pipeline extension is very simple, it only contains decimal numbers, so I want to enable the user to change that file at will and reload it while the game is running (without recompiling as I had to do so far). This file is a very simplified version of level editor, meaning that it contains rows like:
`1 1,5 1,78 -3,6`

Here, the first number determines the object that will be drawn to the scene, and the other 3 numbers are coordinates where that object will be placed.

So, how can I change the file that contains these numbers so that the game loads it and redraws the scene accordingly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content pipeline cannot do that (without a bit of hacking about), it processes content as part of the project's build process.

Just use regular .net functions for monitoring file changes, `FileSystemWatcher` maybe and reading files `File.ReadAllText()`.

Comment: I tried that, I used the code like this:
`if(ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.L)){
sField = File.ReadAllLines("path");
Window.Title = sField[0];
}`
I used this code just to see if the file is being read correctly, but the Title is not changing at all. I placed this code inside the Update function.

Comment: Have you checked that the `ReadAllLines` code runs at all?

Comment: At first it wasn't, I fixed that but now it throws me an error "Access to the path '....' is denied." (when I try to load from my desktop or similar location) or FileNotFound error (when I try to place the file inside the project directory)

Comment: That's an issue with the access rights of the user the program is running as I would think. Maybe ask a question on stackoverflow.com (as it's no longer related to game development).